# Hackerrank Code not working

Tags: python

The problem is given [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/gem-stones)

I am coding in python and my code is given below:

```
num =raw_input()
li=list()
count=150*[0]
ans=0

while num>0:
    li.append(raw_input())
    num=int(num)-1
for i in range (0, len(li)):
    for j in range(0, len(li[i])):
        count.insert (ord(li[i][j]), count[ord(li[i][j])]+1)
for i in range(0, len(count)):
    if count[i]==len(li):
        ans=ans+1
print ans
```

On running the sample test case the output is 3 instead of 2.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your program.

First the insert method doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

> list.insert(i, x)
>
> Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to a.append(x).

Second, you're attempting to count every time a letter appears at all, not just the first instance in a line.

This also looks like a low effort question, which is why you're getting downvoted.  What have you tried?

Here's a solution that uses your method correctly, but it's still not a very pythonic approach.  Have you considered using a dict to keep track of this information instead?

```
num = raw_input()
li = list()
count = 150*[0]
seen = 150*[False]
ans = 0

while num > 0:
    li.append(raw_input())
    num = int(num)-1

for i in range(0, len(li)):
    for j in range(0, len(li[i])):
        if (not seen[ord(li[i][j])]):
            count[ord(li[i][j])] += 1
        seen[ord(li[i][j])] = True
    seen = 150*[False]

print count
for i in range(0, len(count)):
    if count[i] == len(li):
        ans = ans+1
        print chr(i)
print ans
```

Here's the same approach using more pythonic language, isn't this much easier to understand?

```
num = raw_input()
lines = []
seen = set()
count = {}

while num > 0:
    lines.append(raw_input())
    num = int(num)-1

for line in lines:
    for char in line:
        if (char not in seen):
            count[char] = count.get(char, 0) + 1
        seen.add(char)
    seen = set()

print count

print list(count.values()).count(len(lines))
```

There are, of course even better ways to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "you're attempting to count every instance, not just the first instance in a line."? 

And thanks for the answer, I'll edit it to improve it ASAP.

Comment: A gem is defined as "an element that appears in every line."  If you have two lines, one that looks like "abb" and the other that looks like "aa"  You can see that if you count every instance of "a" you'll wind up with 3 "a"s.  Which is different from the number of lines, yet is a gem.  And 2 "b"s which is the same as the number of lines, but is not.

Answer (score 2):

The website states: *Required Knowledge: Implementation, Sets: Time Complexity: O(n)*

So using `set.intersection` would be a better way to go:

```
num = raw_input()

sets  = [set(raw_input()) for x in range(int(num))] ]# make set from each line

print len(set.intersection(*sets)) # find letters that are common in all sets and print the length
```

Comment: Okay. Didn't have any idea about sets. Will read up on it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are counting `c` as a gem-element. It occurs 3 times, but not in 3 different lines. Thus `count[i]==len(li)` is not a sufficient criterion for a gem-element.

Comment: Actually, if you print out which characters are being detected as gems, you can see that it's actually counting "j" as a gem, which doesn't even appear.  The problem is he's using the insert method.